Get maven to build a java application using the values from the application-production.properties rather than from application.properties
I am trying to deploy a spring application in production mode. When I run the application locally with the profile production and set the -Dspring.profiles.active=production, the application will using my sql database. However, when I build with maven and deploy to azure, the application runs in deployment mode. I have confirmed that it is deployment mode as none of the work is stored on the database unlike when it is ran locally. I can also confirm there is no rollback due to having a version string which I have displayed on the login page to let me know if my code is actually being deployed.
Local - Production: Java 19 with Profile set to production and spring.profiles.active set to production

Local - Dev: Java 19 with Profile set to development

Deploy-Development:
mvn install -Pproduction;
az login;
az containerapp up --resource-group rg-group -n group-app-vaadin --source .;

Deploy-Production:
mvn install -Pproduction -Dspring.profiles.active=production; 
az login;
az containerapp up --resource-group rg-group -n group-app-vaadin --source .;

Docker:
FROM eclipse-temurin:21-jre
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]

application.properties:
server.port=${PORT:8080}
logging.level.org.atmosphere=warn
spring.mustache.check-template-location=false

# Launch the default browser when starting the application in development mode
vaadin.launch-browser=true

# increases max file size the server will accept
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=30MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=30MB

# To improve the performance during development.
# For more information https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/integrations/spring/configuration#special-configuration-parameters
vaadin.allowed-packages=com.vaadin,org.vaadin,com.GROUP,de.f0rce.signaturepad
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

application-production.properties:
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://GROUP.database.windows.net:1433;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;loginTimeout=30;database=GROUP-db;
spring.datasource.username=USERNAME
spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD

pom.xml without dependecies
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- Project from https://start.vaadin.com/project/ed548501-5760-489f-8284-368a0c13d375 -->
    <groupId>com.group.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>group-webapp</artifactId>
    <name>Group Web App</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>24.4.6</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->

        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>



    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- Exclude development dependencies from production -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>vaadin-dev</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>development</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>development</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>

First, I tried to debug the build and get maven to display which properties it was loading but couldn't pull it off.
Then I tried to mvn clean and mvn clean -Pproduction in case the build was failing to change the value then attempt another build.
Finally, I simply changed all my application.properties to be exactly the same and made them look what I expected application-production.properties to look like. That still failed to deploy with the values that I see in Local-Production.

You should add to your question your pom file. Unless you have a specific plugin in your pom file reading the spring properties, this has likely no effect: mvn install -Pproduction -Dspring.profiles.active=production; specifically the Dspring.profiles.active=production; this property is read when the application is executed, not compiled.

I tired but according to stack overflow it was considered spam since it was to large.

then remove the dependencies from it, add just the build, properties and plugins configurations.

I have removed the dependencies as requested.

I think you just need to change this on your docker image: from ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"] to ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=<correct profile here>"] try that and see if it works.

I tried with FROM eclipse-temurin:21-jre
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=production", "-Pproduction"]
and ran it with my Deploy production script and it still lead to running the code in development mode. I also tried it without -Pproduction and it lead to the same result.
I apoligize for the late response; my network went down.

So then I would need to see the logs generated from executing your application in the production environment. from start to when spring boot selects the profile. It should have something like: The following 1 profile is active: "local" with whatever profile it selected.

You are correct. I determined that the profile seems to be set to default but if I run the command from docker using --spring.profiles.active=production, I can get it to run locally with profile production but when I tried to deploy it with those requirements it failed.
Does anything in this string seem strange to you? ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","/app.jar", "--spring.profiles.active=production"]

It looks correct. Since it is not picking the parameter being passed in try setting it while configuring the image, add this line to your docker file ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production (before the entrypoint of course) and then use the entrypoint without it see what happens

I have tried that and that has failed as well. It still deploys with the default profile.

I'd like to apologize for wasting your time it seems. It is working now. I didn't know there was a way of forcing an "failed-activation" container back on to force it to write to the logs which I had been trying to get working during this entire process. The issue was that the IP address for the container that I had found previously was incorrect and the ip address from the error log allowed the application to work correctly now.

No problem, happy that you were able to solve it!

The issue was being caused by the fact that my docker file was lacking the correct arguments. I had thought that the *.properties files affected the object at compile time but was elucidated by Jorge Campos that they simply affect the run time.
Orginal
FROM eclipse-temurin:21-jre
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]

Jorge Campos Corrected
FROM eclipse-temurin:21-jre
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]

P.S.
If you are using Azure, click the url for the specific container to force it to activate so you can see the logs as they are not stored anywhere. This will show you what runtime errors your running into.
